# eGit error with zend studio

Tags: git, zend-framework, egit, zend-studio

I'm using Git with Zend Studio verion 10.

here's the senarion, 
I create new branch
I add some code
I commit and push
I want switch branch
=>failing, it throw me this error in the link image below and when I check my code, I found new files and old version of code, so I have to restart my computer an delete the temporary files shown in the image, and reset all the old code(that wasn't added by me)

does anyone can help me with this, and how to prevent this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Cp4eF8WZ5pVkpYNnpQTXdKWEU/edit?usp=sharing